# trouble after publishing BLAZOR website to IIS

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I published my project on the host . My project works on the local system without any problems.

[image: it was Ran on localhosts]

But when publishing on the hosts, it gives an error. The version of IIS in our host is 10.

And my webconfig file content is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\LosacoWeb.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I attached picture of error as follow:
[image: Error Message Picture]

And the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'register')
    at (index):17
/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
dotnet.5.0.4.js:1 mono_wasm_runtime_ready fe00e07a-5519-4dfe-b35a-f867dbaf2e28
blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Arg_TargetInvocationException
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies.
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1 IO_FileName_Name, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[<Main>d__0](<Main>d__0& stateMachine)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at LosacoWeb.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
blazor.webassembly.js:1    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting.EntrypointInvoker.InvokeEntrypoint(String assemblyName, String[] args)
```

After some times checking our code I known that our problem is in JWTAuthenticationStateProvider class. when we published our website without that class Our website works fine. I add that class code as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LosacoWeb.Client.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace LosacoWeb.Client.Auth
{
    public class JWTAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, ILoginService
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime js;
        private readonly string TokenKey = "******";
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private AuthenticationState Anonymous =>
        new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

        public JWTAuthenticationStateProvider(IJSRuntime js, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.js = js;
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }


        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var token = await js.GetFromLocalStorage(TokenKey);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return Anonymous;
            }

            return BuildAuthenticationState(token);
        }

        public AuthenticationState BuildAuthenticationState(string token)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt")));
        }


        private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            var payload = jwt.Split(".")[1];
            var jsonBytes = ParsBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
            var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

            keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(ClaimTypes.Role, out object roles);

            if (roles != null)
            {
                if (roles.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("["))
                {
                    var parsedRoles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.ToString());
                    foreach (var parsedRole in parsedRoles)
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parsedRole));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.ToString()));
                }

                keyValuePairs.Remove(ClaimTypes.Role);
            }

            claims.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())));
            return claims;
        }

        private byte[] ParsBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
        {
            switch (base64.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
                case 3: base64 += "="; break;
            }

            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }

        public async Task Login(string token)
        {
            await js.SetInLocalStorage(TokenKey, token);
            var authState = BuildAuthenticationState(token);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(authState));
        }

        public async Task LogOut()
        {
            await js.RemoveItem(TokenKey);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(Anonymous));
        }
    }
}
```

In program.cs:

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>
        (provider => provider.GetRequiredService<JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>());
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginService, JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>
        (provider => provider.GetRequiredService<JWTAuthenticationStateProvider>());
```

Comment: What are your path related settings mentioned in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hello @Steve Greene thanks for your reply. but our problem does not solved.

Comment: Possibly missing a DLL for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization? It might be worth checking if this dll exists in the deployed version.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Campbell I checked the DLL file and it has not any problem. We use  Dot Net 5 version in our Blazor project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just copy all of scripts in script folder in shared folder into wwwroot folder.
When running WebSite in frameworks higher than 5 in BLAZOR, all the script files used in the mentioned folder must be copied. Because the physical path defined by default in `IIS` does not have direct access to these folders in the shared layer.
best regards.